# build spark on windows from source code

Tags: windows, apache-spark, build, sbt

It would be nice if I could download the source code of spark from github, then build it with sbt on my windows machine, and use IntelliJ to make little modifications to the code base. I have installed spark before on windows quite a few times, but I just use the packaged tarball and not the source code.  Has anyone built the source code on a windows machine before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account also for the simple differences in `\n\r` and `\n`.  So you should use dos2Unix utility for Linux and make sure that you are using an up to date version of Cygwin when installing and running hadoop utils.

Comment: You can set autocrlf = true (Checkout Windows-style, commit Unix-style) for git. That will handle the conversion of line endings during checkout.

Answer (score 0):

I found the spark developer tools page and it was very helpful.  I needed "build/sbt compile"

http://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html#reducing-build-times